# discrepancies between google map search and google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It was suggested that I should post a more detailed question.  Thank you in advance for ANY thoughts or guidance.

Basically, I'm trying to get all the same data from an API request that I get from a standard successful google maps search.

If I search "tractor supply co brentwood tn" in Google Maps, I get this rich result, with lots of details and images for the business. (please click this link to see the full details I'm looking for)
[google maps search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jQ8Y.png)

If I do a google API geocode search like this (ellipses substituted for https:// because I am new to the forum and don't have the rep for multiple link posts yet):

...maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=TRACTOR+SUPPLY+COMPANY+(HQ)+BRENTWOOD+TN&key=mykey

I get this response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Brentwood, TN, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brentwood</long_name>
   <short_name>Brentwood</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamson County</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamson County</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Tennessee</long_name>
   <short_name>TN</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>36.0331164</lat>
    <lng>-86.7827772</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>35.9325590</lat>
     <lng>-86.8698999</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>36.0447090</lat>
     <lng>-86.6868770</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>35.9325590</lat>
     <lng>-86.8698999</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>36.0447090</lat>
     <lng>-86.6868770</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <partial_match>true</partial_match>
  <place_id>ChIJ41xJuq57ZIgRkN_2gzhAfTU</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Which has SOME of the same data, but not all.  It also provides a "placeid".  So if I pull that and do a "details" search based on the placeid like this:

...maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=ChIJ41xJuq57ZIgRkN_2gzhAfTU&key=mykey

I get this result which seems like it is using a generic placeid rather than something specific to this company:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceDetailsResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Brentwood</name>
  <vicinity>Brentwood</vicinity>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Brentwood, TN, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brentwood</long_name>
   <short_name>Brentwood</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamson County</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamson County</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Tennessee</long_name>
   <short_name>TN</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>36.0331164</lat>
    <lng>-86.7827772</lng>
   </location>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>35.9325590</lat>
     <lng>-86.8698999</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>36.0447090</lat>
     <lng>-86.6868770</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <url>https://maps.google.com/?q=Brentwood,+TN,+USA&amp;ftid=0x88647baeba495ce3:0x357d403883f6df90</url>
  <icon>https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CnRvAAAA7imTJVU7NIR2ZHUHP72h0JegnJJsPWEJYswpzCe_UTTGRmcbEjFCC-it8-GKmaMJiIR_oNShYTUTWGrdJkwbmKws1JY8iX_yItYHaiiKuDLZRDfgF8mK0aACDfjfsVJzJFoJsTGHhrUQcD9KtzrvJBIQK5_0vxAqFpN-8xTs3XP5kxoUMQD0mUqBZ2sO8RLcL-Dkhf2ltn8</reference>
  <id>667453c8f258729c704ec5ed39d0ab09e79e8cc6</id>
  <adr_address>&lt;span class=&quot;locality&quot;&gt;Brentwood&lt;/span&gt;, &lt;span class=&quot;region&quot;&gt;TN&lt;/span&gt;, &lt;span class=&quot;country-name&quot;&gt;USA&lt;/span&gt;</adr_address>
  <place_id>ChIJ41xJuq57ZIgRkN_2gzhAfTU</place_id>
  <scope>GOOGLE</scope>
 </result>
</PlaceDetailsResponse>
```

This result also does not contain the full details of a simple google search, or even the full "details" which the documentation says should result from a "details" search.

I've also tried doing a "textsearch" with the place API like so:

...maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=TRACTOR+SUPPLY+COMPANY+(HQ)+BRENTWOOD+TN&key=mykey

Which returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Tractor Supply Company</name>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_address>5401 Virginia Way, Brentwood, TN 37027, United States</formatted_address>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>36.0322092</lat>
    <lng>-86.8131363</lng>
   </location>
  </geometry>
  <rating>3.4</rating>
  <icon>https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CnRpAAAAqLzUG_q4XIngf8xF1dcx-Gofy-uBiBvvZJoLNFFQ1ZoQ83fWx_teRICg_Fbl2dfMd2i1U9pLwYpBFx2fNeB51Yvnb6emO_IaVf7_Ex7HqvbgoawTy06aMuD3H3rr6BITfHg0Qr31a9Fkn2-k3S_UKBIQscPj4YrbojkF7Fw3j8RgMxoUcpgyXPXincWiPyuoTRA6XU9TCJU</reference>
  <id>1733e3c88f2446c3502000eae8ddf94e63b89602</id>
  <opening_hours>
   <open_now>true</open_now>
  </opening_hours>
  <photo>
   <photo_reference>CoQBdwAAANoj0c9wy5uab1aCuip5nlxW1XAU_2wei_XeWUNUM4Cuv3sGTSsyA4zb0qN0OKkaJOAZM7BCJgf4YPtyCvQv4h41UNsxNeT4yOppArK-JOzpOKrJT_WMcbS8c7ormj9-F_Mz5JOLPVV6bWEQKl6gqKvFGVLOpTxP0SEO50TyKffoEhDG0h4EX3lNzLIe9rFOv6nPGhRychAj_sRndkuzHC-cHVgH_wSwEw</photo_reference>
   <width>3264</width>
   <height>2448</height>
   <html_attribution>&lt;a href=&quot;https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102180476513775764202/photos&quot;&gt;Jeremy Haggard&lt;/a&gt;</html_attribution>
  </photo>
  <price_level>2</price_level>
  <place_id>ChIJL-npOFt7ZIgRgaOcl-AVuDU</place_id>
 </result>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Again, not the full set of data available from a simple google map search, or even what we should be able to get from a "detail" search.

So is there a way to format an API request or even multiple API requests which will allow me to retrieve all of this same data?  I can certainly format the search data differently, (e.g. all lowercase or no punctuation,etc) but I've tried that and it didn't seem to matter.  Is there a parameter I should be adding to my query?

I've been at this a while and I'm stuck.  ANY help is GREATLY appreciated.

Update:  Following a comment by geocodezip I tried a slightly different url (I hope this is what you were trying to tell me).  I first did a geocode search on the same terms from above in order to get the lat&long, and then I did a place API search with the lat&long, as follows:  ...//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=35.9325590,-86.8698999&radius=5000&name=TRACTOR|SUPPLY&key=mykey

Tried several different combinations of parameters.  The results were mixed but basically worse than before.  Never the right single result which is provided easily in a google maps search, and often too wide a net and too many results.  Here's one example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Tractor Supply Co.</name>
  <vicinity>1101 Hillview Lane, Franklin</vicinity>
  <type>hardware_store</type>
  <type>home_goods_store</type>
  <type>store</type>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>35.8907643</lat>
    <lng>-86.8778121</lng>
   </location>
  </geometry>
  <rating>4.5</rating>
  <icon>https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CnRlAAAAj6SHHs-lw-RGVupH8Pvd5TH0UxslEwrZfqWt3jlWQoXfQF3F4QwtO6dRHHluYMCmTnUbZkjlb_EjxYdh1xxuKQm1t_HKEb6GFkd5O4etE6IVjVjeC90QsOtCTFi5Y3RkWPbY_bFJxveVulTZ6REhKBIQ311Kf-nQw6elbAclygFtCRoU2ZtPK0g5Arq7CZQ4Yrz_eHJvErc</reference>
  <id>fbcd6594faab6531269569c223a846280cf5694e</id>
  <opening_hours>
   <open_now>true</open_now>
  </opening_hours>
  <photo>
   <photo_reference>CoQBcwAAAAMQPyHJ4tzPHuVwirxpOEdNRduW3YV3qBHKtDPW9TnUWsPx0dyOP9VbUt3Xi2X5iDpiU8KAcpECr6BgI4er67LHi6vIAPPdvKnEVQxEoa0xf7-bWYJC0I8XvOr-pWE-wXth-zxNNrehDhEZ3avD6CCIycxcRMaSt0sbgIAnKf2OEhAkGkj4V_HFnnEsmgXu7xmWGhRqNCKGqYOikAH2bzLG6QC8O6Feew</photo_reference>
   <width>348</width>
   <height>348</height>
   <html_attribution>&lt;a href=&quot;https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117785023973427282224/photos&quot;&gt;Mark Grubb&lt;/a&gt;</html_attribution>
  </photo>
  <price_level>2</price_level>
  <place_id>ChIJF4g295N_ZIgRWFMbRGsSfRc</place_id>
  <scope>GOOGLE</scope>
 </result>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Comment: What information are you missing?  If you do a "details" search on the placeId from the Places API, do you get the rest of the information?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, that is what the second request and results block shows.  It does not include all of the info I was expecting.  I edited my question above to make it more clear that there is a link to a screenshot of the google maps results I would like to capture most of.  Also, if I look at the long list of details which are supposed to result from a "details" search, I am not seeing them in my results.  You'll notice it doesn't even include a company name or street address, much less a phone number.  Just a city and state really.

Comment: The details response you posted in the question is for the placeId in the geocoder result, not for the Place API result (they are different)

Comment: Sorry.  I'm confused.  If I go to this page  https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details  it shows me this url format for a Place API details request  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters  Where one of the required parameters is either the placeid or the deprecated reference.  So I pulled the placeid from a geocode text search result in order to try to get more details, but it actually produces less than the geocode textsearch.  Am I missing something?  I would LOVE for it to be that I was just doing the wrong kind of request.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my question by the way. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the request you were suggesting is what I did in the third request/codeblock listed above. A  place API request based on textsearch,  I also just tried something else I thought you might have been referring to and added it to the bottom of my post as a fourth block.  Are either of these what you meant?  These are all successful requests, but with incomplete data.  Is there another way I should be formatting my request or requests to get more of the available data?

Comment: Thank you geocodezip.  I kept at it and finally figured out what you were saying.  I did the place api textsearch and grabbed the placeid from THERE instead, and then used that in a placeid search and got rich results.  was confused because I had read that there can be multiple placeid's for a single location but they were always the same location. Looks like I was just using the wrong placeid result.   I think this will work Thank you SO much.  How can I give you credit for this answer?

Comment: I have entered an answer.  If this addresses your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeId for the geocoded result and the places search are different.  For the results from the **place**, use the placeId retrieved from the directions service.

You are doing the details request on (the place_id in the geocoder response):

```
<place_id>ChIJ41xJuq57ZIgRkN_2gzhAfTU</place_id>
```

Instead use (the place_id in the Places API response):

```
<place_id>ChIJF4g295N_ZIgRWFMbRGsSfRc</place_id>
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks.  This did help greatly and I am able to get much better results this way.  But before I close out the question, it still does not provide all the same info I can get from a google maps search.  There is a description field which appears to be the way the business describes itself, especially key words they may have entered for their business.  I can't seem to get that from this search.  Also trying to pull a street view from this placeid sometimes works, but often produces no results when the google maps search has one.  Even in prominent populated places. Any way to get the rest?